# Normalization of a vector using loops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector

Write a function that normalizes a vector (finds the unit vector). A vector can be normalized by dividing each individual component of the vector by its magnitude. Your input for this function will be a vector i.e. 1 dimensional list containing 3 integers.

According to the solution devised, I have considered a predefined list of 3 elements. But if I want to apply loops, then please explain me that how I could deduce the solution using loops. I tried working on the problem. This is my solution so far:

```
from math import sqrt
def vector_normalization(my_vector):
  result = 0
  for x in my_vector:
    result = result + (x ** 2)
    magnitude = sqrt(result)
  nx_vector = my_vector[0] / magnitude
  ny_vector = my_vector[1] / magnitude
  nz_vector = my_vector[2] / magnitude
  n_vector = [nx_vector, ny_vector, nz_vector]
  return n_vector
```

Now, after I calculate the magnitude using for loop of some random list, according to my program I will get only three elements in the list as the output. But I want all the elements in the random list to be normalized. Please suggest me the way to achieve the same.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new here. Please let me know how can I post my code. If I paste in comment, the whole code comes in a paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use high order functions in `Python` like `map`:

```
vec = [1,2,3]
magnitude = sqrt(sum(map(lambda x: x**2, vec)))
normalized_vec = list(map(lambda x: x/magnitude, vec))
```

So `normalized_vec` becomes:

```
[0.2672612419124244, 0.5345224838248488, 0.8017837257372732]
```

Or using `Numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,2,3])
arr_normalized = arr/sqrt(sum(arr**2))
```

`arr_normalized` results in:

```
array([ 0.26726124,  0.53452248,  0.80178373])
```

Comment: There is a `numpy.linalg.norm` that can help you getting the norm of the vector.

Comment: Yes, that's for sure. As he's basically attempting a solution on his own, I think it's more appropriate to show different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code,

```
vector = [1,2,4]
y=0
for x in vector:
    y+=x**2

y = y**0.5
unit_vector = []
for x in vector:
    unit_vector.append(x/y)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
def vector_normalization(vec):
    result = 0
    for x in vec:
        result = result + (x**2)
        magnitude = (result)**0.5
        x = vec[0]/magnitude
        y = vec[1]/magnitude
        z = vec[2]/magnitude
        vec = [x,y,z]
    return vec
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.